# interact with n (random) radio buttons groups generated dynamically

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I want to interact with groups of radio button that are generated for each record on my database.
I want to be able to edit each record and change the radio button choose before save.
This is my html code

```
<script type="text/template" id="item-template">
  <li class="<%= done ? 'completed' : '' %>">
<div class="view">

  <label class="edit-shopname"><%= shopname %></label>
  <label class="edit-shopadress"><%= shopadress %></label>
  <label class="edit-shopsize"><%= shopsize %></label>
  <button class="all-edit"></button>
  <button class="todo-destroy"></button>
</div>
<div class="divedit">

    <input class="edit" value="<%= shopname %>">
    <input class="edit2" value="<%= shopadress %>">
    <div class="radiobutton">
    <input type="radio" name="edit_rbshopsize" value="small">Small 
    <input type="radio" name="edit_rbshopsize" value="medium">Medium 
    <input type="radio" name="edit_rbshopsize" value="large">Large
    <label id="rbshopsize_var" style = "display:none;"><%= shopsize %></label>

    </div>
    <button class="save"></button>

</div>
  </li>
</script>
```

Example of 2 records open for edit at same time
[example of my app](http://petiscosecompanhia.pt/shop.png)

Comment: something like `$('input[type=radio]')` and maybe `.click()` the ones you want selected?

Comment: i think the problem is the name="edit_rbshopsize", for each record there is a instance of name="edit_rbshopsize". for that reason i can't control each group. Maybe there is a way to give unique name for each radio button group that aper a on screen. For example name="%= uniqueRB %" and some function to give names like  edit_rbshopsize1, edit_rbshopsize2... etc...

Comment: Yes, that can definitely be a problem.  Radio inputs are grouped by name, so they should be unique for each group that you want.  Just append a number at the end `_1`, `_2`, `_3`.

Comment: ok, here i need help. how can make this line  with name variable?<input type="radio" name="edit_rbshopsize" value="small">Small after that i can try the javascript side thanks

Comment: I really can't tell how you've built this from the example.  I would guess start it at 0 then when you dynamically create more (with JavaScript) append the index of the `.divedit` div? If so, just do `<input type="radio" name="edit_rbshopsize_0" value="small">`, then create new inputs with name `'edit_rbshopsize_' + $('.divedit').length;`  Something like that.